# Should I create an app for every page? (Django)

Tags: django

I'm new to Django. I am currently trying to bring my static html/css website to Django (mainly for learning).
My only doubt is: *should I use a new app for every page I have?*

The doubt comes from the fact that the title which I'll give to the pages are different, hence making page_title variable requires me to write in views.py, but I can't (maybe I'm wrong) write multiple page_title variables inside the same app's views.py.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, by default you can create a 'template' folder in your app folder and when you render inside a view Django will search the template there. So, you can create many html files as you want.

Also, you can change the templates folder location to make it more 'global' and have only one template folder.

Here an example of how you can organize your project:

- home_app
- - views.py
- - models.py
- - templates/
- - - home.html
- - - contact.html
- - - login.html
- dashboard_app
- - views.py
- - models.py
- - templates/
- - - index.html
- - - users.html
- - - statistics.html

[Here is a link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/templates/#configuration) for global folder location if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks! And what about the page title? EDIT: Doubt solved, sorry.